# Grafana - send an email from custom panel plugin

Tags: plugins, grafana, grafana-plugin

I created a custom panel plugin (TypeScript + React) that get data from ElasticSearch to monitor our systems. The plugin with custom logic (based on data) shows the state of the systems. Now I would like to send an email to a SMS gateway (or even to voice gateway). That just means send an email to a specific email address with phone numbers in the subject and a body with a specific format.

As far as I know Grafana can send an email via alerts that are linked with some graph panel and some threshold. I don't have any of that.

Is there a way to send (trigger via code) an email when my panel logic detects an error/warning? Do I have to write the sending logic (in the panel) myself with some nodeJS lib (without grafana) or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

From Grafana [forum](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-send-emails-from-a-custom-panel-plugin/62171):

> AFAIK there’s no official plugin support for sending emails, so I’m
> afraid you’d need to implement it yourself.

So I plan to user nodeJS library nodemailer to send en email from the panel plugin.